# webdriver effective window switching for IE in C#?

Tags: c#, internet-explorer, window, webdriver, window-handles

I am in the process of writing out some test automation for a website.  What my test is supposed to do is: run through a list of links that each provide their own window, check the data in the window, then close the child window and revert back to the parent window.

While I can access each link, I can't switch focus to the child windows.  And driver.WindowHandles only shows one handle (It didn't do that the previous day).  I have been stuck on this issue for the past two days and it feels like I have just been going backward.  Any and all help would be appreciated.

Below is the portion of my code

```
if (pop_continue)
{
      //windowsBefore = 1
      wait.Until((_driver) => { return _driver.WindowHandles.Count != windowsBefore; });
      ReadOnlyCollection<string> Handles = driver.WindowHandles;
      foreach (var handle in Handles)
      {
            if (!handle.Equals(baseWindowHndl))
            {
                  driver.SwitchTo().Window(handle);
                  break;
            }
      }
      try
      {
            Console.WriteLine("Child Window (a) " + driver.CurrentWindowHandle);
            //..

            driver.SwitchTo().Window(baseWindowHndl); //baseWindowHndl is initialized to parent handle
            Console.WriteLine("Parent Window (b) " + driver.CurrentWindowHandle);
      }
      catch (Exception e)
      {
             Console.WriteLine("<-Something stupid occurred.->");
             Console.WriteLine(e.Source + " : " + e.Message);
      }
      //////////////
}
```

Comment: I posted an answer to this similar question here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/18263396/2687550