# Handling the popup window in Selenium WebDriver doesn't work

Tags: java, selenium, webdriver, selenium-webdriver

WebDriver launches browser and navigates to the URL and clicks a link in the application, then a new browser with pop-up window appears and we can't get any control with the browser till we close the pop-up window.

The pop-up has only "OK" button. I have tried `switchTo()`, window handler, but doesn't work. Also, not able to get the control of the browser as this popup blocks.

Comment: Posting code and error messages would help.

Comment: Please show the code or screenshots. By "popup window", some mean actual browser window, some mean iframe popup, some mean HTML div popup, some mean alerts. Which one are you talking about?

Comment: Have you used `driver.switchTo().alert().accept();`

Answer (score 1):

You have to provide the window handle when switching to the popup so you can control whats going on there. I use this class to make it easier to switch back and forth.

This is in C#:

```
public class WindowManager
{
    private string _parentWindowHandle;
    private string _popupWindowHandle;

    public void SwitchWindowFocusToPopup(IWebDriver driver, string NewWindowTitle)
    {        
        //pass the expected popup window title so the IWebDriver can get 
        //the windowhandle and assign it to the current iWebDriver

        IWebDriver popup = null;

        var windowIterator = driver.WindowHandles;

        foreach (var windowHandle in windowIterator)
        {
            popup = driver.SwitchTo().Window(windowHandle);
            if (popup.Title == NewWindowTitle)
            {
                _popupWindowHandle = popup.CurrentWindowHandle;
                break;
            }
        }

    }

    #region Properties

    public string ParentWindowHandle
    {
        get
        {
            return _parentWindowHandle;
        }
        set
        {
            _parentWindowHandle = value;
        }
    }

    public string PopupWindowHandle
    {
        get
        {
            return _popupWindowHandle;
        }
        set
        {
            _popupWindowHandle = value;
        }

    }
    #endregion 
}
```

then in my program I do this:

```
WindowManager windowManager = new WindowManager();
windowManager.ParentWindowHandle = driver.CurrentWindowHandle;
//do stuff that opens the new window
//immediately switch focus to the popup so webdriver can work with the page
windowManager.SwitchWindowFocusToPopup(driver, "popup window title");

//do stuff with the popup

//close the popup
driver.Close();

//set the webdriver window back to the original parent window
driver.SwitchTo().Window(windowManager.ParentWindowHandle);`
```